# How to use functions of Xcode projects in workspace?

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, xcode

I have an Objective-C function `FirstFunc` in my project 'A' in Xcode.
I have a Swift function `SecondFunc` in my project 'B' in Xcode.
Projects 'A' and 'B' are in the Xcode workspace.
How I can call `SecondFunc` of project 'B' with my `FirstFunc` of project 'A'?

Any ideas?

I'm beginner of iOS development and don't have ideas about that.

Comment: What do those projects produce? frameworks? apps?

Comment: @klangfarb apps

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to share code directly between 2 apps in 2 projects. But you can:

1. Isolate whatever code you want to share (e.g. `FirstFunc`) into a separate project
2. Include it into both apps, like explained [here](https://medium.com/kinandcartacreated/modular-ios-splitting-a-workspace-into-modules-331293f1090) for example, or by making a common code an `xcframework` and consuming via cocoapods or package, as explained [here](https://www.appcoda.com/xcframework/)

This is the most suitable solution for most cases. But if both of your apps share *most* of the code (and most differences are in configuration or assets), then you can also do this:

1. Combine both apps into 1 project,
2. Create a separate *target* for each app. Each target will include common code, and bits specific to the particular app.

But like I said, this is only suitable if most of the code is shared, otherwise it becomes a mess.